# Login with facebook with js sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

> I am trying to do login with facebook but their is an error and is not allowing users to login and the error is  ERROR: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

```
           <html>
           <head>
             <title>Login with Facebook</title>
           </head>
           <body>

             <div id="fb-root"></div>
             <script>
         window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
           FB.init({
             appId      : '555437747988297',
             channelUrl : '//booknow.drbatras.ae/channel.html', // Channel File
             xfbml      : true,
             version    : 'v2.7'
           });
         };

         (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
       </script>

         <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>

       </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to developers site of facebook -> login with the admin account of your app and select your app from the menu, In the Advanced settings tab of the app add your domains then the error will not show up

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the channelUrl parameter (it is not needed anymore)
- Add the "Website" Platform in your App settings, with your URL
- Add the domain at "App Domains" in your App settings